# Got "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2" while trying to create ODI Partial Tag VCS

Tags: java, oracle, version-control, indexoutofboundsexception, oracle-data-integrator

I got the error message below from ODI Studio (12.2.1.4) when I tried to drag and drop a package into "Objects to be Added" area to create Partial Tag inside my VCS (which is Gitlab).  Please see the captured screenshot below.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils$1$2.doAction(DependencyUtils.java:786)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.dwgobject.DwgObjectTemplate.execute(DwgObjectTemplate.java:203)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils$1.doInTransaction(DependencyUtils.java:762)
    at oracle.odi.core.persistence.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:100)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.getDependenciesInternal(DependencyUtils.java:720)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.getDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:680)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.getDependenciesInternal(DependencyUtils.java:634)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.getDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:617)
    at oracle.odi.ui.vcs.VcsPartialTagDialog.populateTree(VcsPartialTagDialog.java:537)
    at oracle.odi.ui.smartie.common.SmartieUtils.populateTree(SmartieUtils.java:266)
    at oracle.odi.ui.smartie.common.OdiObjectTreeTransferHandlerSmartie.importData(OdiObjectTreeTransferHandlerSmartie.java:88)
    at oracle.odi.ui.vcs.VcsPartialTagTreeTransferHandler.importData(VcsPartialTagTreeTransferHandler.java:66)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler.importData(TransferHandler.java:827)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$DropHandler.drop(TransferHandler.java:1544)
    at java.awt.dnd.DropTarget.drop(DropTarget.java:455)
    at javax.swing.TransferHandler$SwingDropTarget.drop(TransferHandler.java:1282)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.processDropMessage(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:538)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchDropEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:852)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer$EventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:776)
    at sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetEvent.dispatch(SunDropTargetEvent.java:48)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processDropTargetEvent(Container.java:4609)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4471)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper._dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:169)
    at oracle.javatools.internal.ui.EventQueueWrapper.dispatchEvent(EventQueueWrapper.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpLinkScenTaskDestLSchema.getLogicalSchemas(SnpLinkScenTaskDestLSchema.java:67)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dbobj.SnpLinkScenTaskDestLSchema.getInstanceLstAction(SnpLinkScenTaskDestLSchema.java:34)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.DwgLink.getInstanceLst(DwgLink.java:132)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.findDwgObjectDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:389)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.findDwgObjectDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:397)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.findDwgObjectDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:397)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.findDwgObjectDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:397)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.getLstDependencies(DependencyUtils.java:459)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils.access$000(DependencyUtils.java:86)
    at com.sunopsis.dwg.dep.DependencyUtils$1$2.doAction(DependencyUtils.java:776)
    ... 48 more
```

[image: The screenshot]

I'm not sure if it relates, but recently, I upgraded my ODI repositories from 11g to 12c (12.2.1.4) without any issues.  I have tried using different packages, machines, and accounts, and found the same issue.

Comment: It looks like it fails when trying to retrieve the logical schema linked to your object. Can you make sure the Logical schema correctly exists and that the user you use have access to it?

Comment: Yes.  The logical schema exists and I have access to all objects, and I also successfully created a tag with that package before.  It seems the error happened after I generate a scenario from the package that does not make sense.